# Comportamiento inesperado usando Angular Material

Tags: angularjs-2.0, system.js, angular-material

Estoy realizando una aplicación usando Angular 2.

He seguido los pasos descritos en la [documentación oficial](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) para utilizar Angular Material en mi aplicación. (Excepto los mappings de SystemJS el cual no estoy utilizando)

Todo parece funcionar correctamente, es decir, no hay errores en la consola, excepto que los componentes no funcionan del todo bien, como si no se cargasen los estilos correctamente o faltara algo.

En mi `app.component.scss` tengo lo siguiente (Añado un tema de Angular Material)

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.scss';

.spacer {
  // This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox. 
  // Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout.
  -webkit-box-flex : 1;
  -ms-flex : 1 1 auto;
  flex : 1 1 auto;
}
```

Y el contenido del html del componente principal `app.component.html`:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Título</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
  </button>
  <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item>
      <md-icon>fingerprint</md-icon>
      <span>Login</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item>
      <md-icon>fingerprint</md-icon>
      <span>Registrarse</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item>
      <md-icon>fingerprint</md-icon>
      <span>Acerca de</span>
    </button>
  </md-menu>
</md-toolbar>

<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="Mapa">Mapa</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Configuración">Config</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Como digo el comportmiento de los componentes no parece funcionar del todo bien y en la siguiente imagen se puede ver claro a lo que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, el menú no aprece debajo del botón que ejecuta la acción para abrir el menú. Los tabs no tienen estilo, el efecto ripple de los botones no funciona etc.

¿Qué puede estar pasando o qué me puede faltar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He descubierto qué estaba pasando. Estaba importando el tema `~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.scss` desde `app.component.scss`, el lugar correcto es `styles.scss` dentro de la carpeta `src`:

**styles.scss**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.scss';
```